# Serenity Screenplay run tests from CLI

Tags: java, testing, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Is there a way to execute Serenity Screenplay tests via CLI?
I've tried to issue the `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="list of test files"` command but Maven is not executing anything. 
Currently, this is the main class that I have under src/test/java

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    @RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/NuovoClienteCreazione.feature", format = {"pretty", "html:target/Destination"})
    public class CucumberMain {
    }
```

Also, the pom.xml file has the following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>EPP</groupId>
    <artifactId>AutomationTesting</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>



<dependencies>

    <!-- region: Cucumber e Serenity -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.89</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.48</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sql2o/sql2o -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sql2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>sql2o</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/ojdbc7.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.89</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.89</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.89</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- endregion -->



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- endregion -->


    <!-- region: Drivers di Selenium -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-ie-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


</project>
```

Has anyone ever encountered such an issue while using Serenity Screenplay and was able to execute the tests from CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I discovered that I had first to setup the Failsafe plugin, and then make it communicate with the CucumberMain class.
Then, from the CLI, executing either mvn verify or mvn test with the list of tests that I want to execute made the trick